# How do I replace the e-mail form to functional e-mail subscription?

Tags: plugins, email, subscription

In `front-page.php` I have an e-mail form prototype in HTML:

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter your e-mail address">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Get notified</button>
```

---

Most Wordpress plugin I found is usually a subscription form in widget and send subscribers e-mail automatically when there's a new blog post. This isn't what I'm looking for.

I'm looking for a system that allow visitor to enter their e-mail address and their e-mail address will be added in a file, something like CSV format, so I could use an e-mail program (or Wordpress) to send them e-mail when I need to. I'm not picky, just anything that would work.

Is there any Wordpress plugin that help me to achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sending mass emails I wouldn't recommend sending them from your email program nor from WordPress; instead, I would recommend a third-party service that specializes in sending emails - in particular, I usually recommend [MailChimp](http://mailchimp.com/) as they offer a free subscription level that is usually sufficient. They also provide a easy-to-use WP plugin that allows visitors to sign up to your email list.